# Deleting commas(',') from specif columns not from the complete table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server database. Some columns are separated with commas(','). My task is to remove those commas(',') from the column. Only specific columns, not all.

```
t1     t2   t3   t4     t5
0     2,3   1,5  1,12   2,12
5     5,4   1,1  1,01   1,1
0     0,15  1,3  1,01   2,3
0,55  1,10  3,10 1,2    1,9
0,12  0,15  0,99 1,8    1,7
```

Like I want to remove commas(,) only from t1, t2, and t3 not from the remaining columns.

[image: For example]

Comment: It should be simply matter of updating the column with use of function to replace , with empty string

Comment: So these values are strings and you want say `0,55` to be `055`?

Comment: @forpas yes...exactly

Comment: @Jacob H ..thank you so much for editing it properly....

Comment: No problem! Four spaces begins a code block (or you can highlight a section of text and click the button that looks like this { }).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
update tablename
set
  t1 = replace(t1, ",", ""),
  t2 = replace(t2, ",", ""),
  t3 = replace(t3, ",", "")
where t1 like '%,%' or t2 like '%,%' or t3 like '%,%'
```